# Efficiently select rows that match one of several values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

### Problem

Given data in a Pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
Name     Amount
---------------
Alice       100
Bob          50
Charlie     200
Alice        30
Charlie      10
```

I want to select all rows where the `Name` is one of several values in a collection `{Alice, Bob}`

```
Name     Amount
---------------
Alice       100
Bob          50
Alice        30
```

### Question

What is an efficient way to do this in Pandas?

Options as I see them

1. Loop through rows, handling the logic with Python
2. Select and merge many statements like the following

   ```
   merge(df[df.name = specific_name] for specific_name in names) # something like this
   ```
3. Perform some sort of join

What are the performance trade-offs here?  When is one solution better than the others?  What solutions am I missing?

While the example above uses strings my actual job uses matches on 10-100 integers over millions of rows and so fast NumPy operations may be relevant.

Comment: "my actual job is numeric": what your *actual* problem is matters a lot.  If you need to have a tolerance for floats, for example, you won't be able to use the same solution as you would for strings.

Comment: @DSM edited to specify that I'm matching on integers.  Also added scale of problem.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use the [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) Series method:

```
In [11]: df['Name'].isin(['Alice', 'Bob'])
Out[11]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool

In [12]: df[df.Name.isin(['Alice', 'Bob'])]
Out[12]: 
    Name  Amount
0  Alice     100
1    Bob      50
3  Alice      30
```

Comment: This is indeed the interface I'm looking for.  How does it work under the hood?

Comment: Looks like it's using a Cython for loop over the data and `set.__contains__` to test membership

Comment: Yup, checkout pandas.lib.ismember, it's as you say! Interesting that it uses set rather than khash.

Comment: Is it possible to specify a regex here for the value that is checked. Suppose the value in a row for a particular column in the table is 'hello world foo bar' and I need to return this row if the string 'foo' is present in the column.

Comment: @aditya yes, use [`df['Name'].str.contains('foo')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndyHayden

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 8):

Since, in your actual use case, the values in `df['Name']` are `ints`, you might be able to generate the boolean mask faster using NumPy indexing instead of `Series.isin`.

```
idx = np.zeros(N, dtype='bool')
idx[names] = True
df[idx[df['Name'].values]]
```

---

For example, given this setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(N, size=(10**6, 2)), columns=['Name', 'Amount'])
names = np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=100, replace=False)
```

---

```
In [81]: %timeit idx = np.zeros(N, dtype='bool'); idx[names] = True; df[idx[df['Name'].values]]
100 loops, best of 3: 9.88 ms per loop

In [82]: %timeit df[df.Name.isin(names)]
10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop

In [83]: 107/9.88
Out[83]: 10.82995951417004
```

---

`N` is (essentially) the maximum value that `df['Names']` can attain.
If `N` is smaller, the speed benefit is not as large. With `N = 200`,

```
In [93]: %timeit idx = np.zeros(N, dtype='bool'); idx[names] = True; df[idx[df['Name'].values]]
10 loops, best of 3: 62.6 ms per loop

In [94]: %timeit df[df.Name.isin(names)]
10 loops, best of 3: 178 ms per loop

In [95]: 178/62.6
Out[95]: 2.8434504792332267
```

---

Caution: As shown above, there seems to be a speed benefit, particularly as `N` gets large. However, if `N` is too large, then forming `idx = np.zeros(N, dtype='bool')` may not be feasible.

---

Sanity check:

```
expected = df[df.Name.isin(names)]
idx = np.zeros(N, dtype='bool')
idx[names] = True
result = df[idx[df['Name'].values]]
assert expected.equals(result)
```

Comment: I wonder if perf of isin could be improved using khash rather than set in lib.ismember for large sets (esp. for int/non-object use case).

Comment: @AndyHayden: Unfortunately, I know almost nothing about khash. Where can I learn about it?

Comment: Well, I've just been checking out the source in pandas's hashtables. Looks like could use e.g `h = pd.hashtable.Int64HashTable()`.

Comment: Your way is still **significantly** faster (though certainly HashTable is significantly better than set).

Comment: Actually looking back at your timeits something weird was going on earlier, will have to check this out again. (I was seeing your method a thousand times faster, which can't be right and isn't what you see)

Comment: df['Name'] are not 'ints'.

Comment: @RukTech: The OP's question states (at the end), "While the example above uses strings my actual job uses matches on 10-100 integers over millions of rows and so fast NumPy operations may be relevant."

Comment: Even then the purpose is to find specific strings or 'ints'. Using a randomly generated index (names = np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=100, replace=False)) to access certain rows of the dataframe will be fast. The purpose to find targeted rows of the dataframe.

Comment: This is very interesting. I compared use of `isin` against indexing with Numpy, and for my case, where N varied between 14 and 6000 per data frame, `isin` was always faster. (My use case is similar to the OP, but for mine, I am matching integer columns in 2 data frames, against each other).

Comment: Small note: instead of `idx = np.zeros(N, dtype='bool')` followed by `idx[names] = True` one can use `idx = np.ones(N, dtype='bool')`