# Use For loop in an If statement

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

### Problem

I have a table made of 380 rows and 20 columns. I want to remove rows from this table following a certain condition.

To clarify things, let's say I have the list:

```
names = ['John', 'Amy', 'Daniel']
```

I want to remove the data of all the people whose name is found in the list `names`.

Example, let's say my data looks something like this:

```
John    82    3.12    boy
Katy    12    1.12    girl
Amy     42    2.45    girl
Robert  32    1.56    boy
Daniel  47    2.10    boy
```

I want to remove the data of `John`, `Amy`, and `Daniel`. So the output should be:

```
Katy    12    1.12    girl
Robert  32    1.56    boy
```

### Attempt to solve it

```
import csv
import numpy as np

# loading data
data = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', dtype = None)

csvfile = "home/paula/Desktop/test.txt"
with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = '\t')

    for row in range(len(data)):
        if data[row][0] == (i for i in names):
            print 'removing the data of', i, '...'
        else:
            writer.writerow([data[row][0], data[row][1], 
                             data[row][2], data[row][3]])
```

My code is working, however the data was not deleted from my original data. When I open the new test.txt file, I can see that the data was not deleted.

I am certain that the bug is in `if data[row][0] == (i for i in names):`
How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `data` ? Where do you define it?

Comment: @MrE, I do not have an error, the script works fine. But when I check the output, the `test.txt` file, I can see that I still have the same data.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso, I edited the question, I am loading the data using `np.genfromtxt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition should be written:

```
if data[row][0] in names:
```

In your current code, `(i for i in names)` creates a generator and you are then testing if the string is equal to the generator object, which will be false

```
>>> (i for i in names)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1060564b0>
>>> 'John' == (i for i in names)
False
>>>
```

Instead, you can test if an item is in a list as follows

```
>>> names = ['John', 'Amy', 'Daniel']
>>> 'John' in names
True
>>> 'Bob' in names
False
>>>
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can make this check more efficient by converting `names` to a `set` before iterating over the rows. But ideally you would use the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library to manipulate csv/table data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22485573/553404) for a similar example. You can negate the condition with `df[~df.Name.isin(...)]`.

Comment: making names a set would be a lot more efficient

Comment: It would, but I wanted to explain the issues with the current method as concisely as possible. I added a link to Pandas, which will be more efficient than any hand-crafted code using `set`. I'll add a few words about it.

Comment: I would appreciate it if there is a better way to write the code. Especially that I am not satisfied by the last line: `writer.writerow([ ... ])`. As I've said above, my data is made up of 20 columns, so in the `writer.writerow` I had to write 20 columns!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're checking whether `data[row][0]` is the same as `(i for i in names)`. What you want to do is check whether it's the same as one of the *elements* of `(i for i in names)`. You could do that this way:

```
any([data[row][0]==i for i in names])
```

You could also do it the non-ridiculous way, with the `in` operator:

```
data[row][0] in names
```

This checks whether any of the elements of `names` is the same as `data[row][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if data[row][0] == (i for i in names):
            print 'removing the data of', i, '...'
```

in that portion `i` is use in  `(i for i in names)` as a local veriable. But in next print line you use `i`. Here you can not use this.

you can use for check as `if data[row][0] in names:`. You can try like:

```
if data[row][0] ==  names:
            print 'removing the data of', data[row][0], '...'
```